# Element transform transition between appearing 'relative' and 'fixed' not smooth

Tags: javascript, css, position, transform

I have a page with a banner (`.banner`) and a floating element (`.float`).

When the user is scrolling with the banner in view, I want the `.float` to appear relative to the banner (centred vertically), but when the user scrolls past the banner, it sticks to the screen.

In reality, the position of float is always `fixed` and I am using Javascript to change the transform value to position it where I want on scroll.

It's almost working as I want, but I want the element to 'slide' between positions and I can't get this behaviour to work as I want. Without a CSS transition, it jumps. With a CSS transition, it slides, but when I scroll back up it slides too far above the vertical center of the banner; I want it to feel like it 'sticks' to the banner once you have scrolled back up to the banner.

Any help appreciated. JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/L452xf7h/12/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="banner"></div>
  <div class="float">Floating Element</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body, html {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  background: orange;
  height: 2000px;
}

.banner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background: white;
}

.float {
  display: none;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px;
  right: 100px;
  /* this transition makes float travel high in banner when scrolling up */
  /* transition: transform .3s linear; */
}
```

JS:

```
var float = document.querySelector('.float');

if (float) {
    // init position
  onScroll();
  // check on scroll
  window.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
}

function onScroll() {
var banner_height = 400;
var float_topCss = 100;
var float_height = 50;
  if (window.scrollY < banner_height) {
    position = 0;
    // center vertically in banner
    position += banner_height / 2;
    position -= float_height / 2;
    // account for current scroll
    position -= window.scrollY;
    // minus difference of top css value
    position -= float_topCss;
    float.style.transform = "translate3d(0,"+position+"px,0)";
  }
  else {
    float.style.transform = "translate3d(0,0,0)";
  }
  float.style.display = 'block';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this the result you are looking for?

```js
    var float = document.querySelector('.float');

    if (float) {
     // init position
      onScroll();
      // check on scroll
      window.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
    }

    function onScroll() {
    var banner_height = 400;
      if (window.scrollY < banner_height) {
        float.classList.remove('sticky');
      }
      else {
        float.classList.add('sticky');
      }
    }
```

```css
    body, html {
      margin: 0;
    }

    .container {
      background: orange;
      height: 2000px;
      position: relative;
    }

    .banner {
      width: 100%;
      height: 400px;
      background: white;
    }

    .float {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      background: red;
      position: absolute;
      top: 100px;
      right: 100px;
      float: right;
      transition: transform .3s linear;
    }

    .float.sticky {
      top: -50px;
      transform: translateY(150px);
      position: sticky;
    }
```

```html
    
    <div class="container">
      <div class="banner"></div>
      <div class="float">Floating Element</div>
    </div>
```